# How to connect to SQL Server Management Studio with changing IP address

Tags: sql-server, ip, ssms

I need to work with another team on a project to which I need to connect to a remote DB. I am on ADSL so my IP address changes all the time and every time it changes I need to let the remote guys know so that they can allow my new IP address.

Is there a way, using DYNdns for that IP address to be updated autmogically? Or at least to set up a script that checks my IP address, sends it off to them and then updates their SQL Server Management Studio?

Many thanks!

Comment: Where's your IP being changed? at your PC? at a router? if it's being done at a 'remote' place, you'll be somewhat limited in what you can do locally to detect the changes.

Comment: OT but, FWIW: Well, **yes**, DYNdns and other similar providers support frequent IP updates with their custom client tools. Just make sure the target uses the *domain name* to connect.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion can be to use: http://www.no-ip.com/

Example you can run a server on a dynamic IP with a **dynamic update client to keep track of your dynamic IP address**.

[Check here for more info about this free service](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html)

Hope it help